# LARGE_INTEGER or TLargeInteger?

Tags: delphi

In `Windows.pas`, there are:

```
  LARGE_INTEGER = record
    case Integer of
    0: (
      LowPart: DWORD;
      HighPart: Longint);
    1: (
      QuadPart: LONGLONG);
  end;

  TLargeInteger = Int64;
```

I see several Windows functions and structure members which is originally declared as `LARGE_INTEGER` has been translated to `TLargeInteger` such as:

```
  function QueryPerformanceCounter(var lpPerformanceCount: TLargeInteger): BOOL;
      stdcall;
```

and another example is:

```
  WIN32_STREAM_ID = record
    dwStreamId        : DWORD;
    dwStreamAttributes: DWORD;
    Size              : TLargeInteger;
    dwStreamNameSize  : DWORD;
    cStreamName       : array[0..0] of WCHAR;
  end;
```

Can `TLargeInteger` acts as a replacement of `LARGE_INTEGER` for every function parameters and structure members found in Windows header files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always safely use these two types interchangeably in API translations. Although, clearly, once you have selected one type for a particular function, you have to stick to that type whenever you call that function.

- Using `TLargeInteger` makes it easier to assign values because there's no need to refer to a record field.
- Using `LARGE_INTEGER` makes it easier to separate into low and high 32 bit parts.

Now that the compiler has good support for 64 bit integers, it probably makes more sense to use `TLargeInteger`. Because, usually, there is no need to separate the 64 bit integer into its low and high parts. But way back when the compiler couldn't handle 64 bit integer types, there was no other option to work with 64 bit integers.

Comment: @David_Heffernan, I see, thanks. One more, in 32-bit compiler, is `Int64` internally implemented as a record?

Comment: No, it's a primative type built into the compiler. I think there's some run time library support needed, but it is not a record as such.

Comment: `Int64` is a supported data type in the CPU itself, like `Integer` is. The RTL doesn't have to so anything special to support `Int64`, it lets the CPU handle it like any other integral data type.

Comment: @Remy Is that the case even on 32 bit processors?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes, it is. 32bit processors have supported basic 64bit integer arithmetic operations for a long time. It is not general support for 64bit integers that determines whether a CPU is 64bit or not.

Comment: @Remy What instructions does x86-32 offer then that do arithmetic on 64 bit wide operands?

Comment: I double-checked. A 32-bit CPU does not directly support 64-bit arithmetic afterall, but it is possible to accomplish on a 32-bit CPU. Delphi uses the `ADD` and `ADC` opcodes for 64-bit addition, the `SUB` and `SBB` opcodes for 64-bit substraction, the RTL `llmul()` function (which just wraps the `MUL` and `ADD` opcodes) for 64-bit multiplication, and the RTL `lldiv()` function (which uses a ton of opcodes, so not very efficient from a CPU standpoint) for 64-bit division.

Comment: Either way, you don't have to worry about those details in your code. Just use `Int64` as-is like any other integer type and let the compiler handle the details for you.

Comment: @Remy Yes, that's what I thought.